# font family wont change CSS h2 and h3 tags, importing from google fonts

Tags: html, css

The import from google fonts shows that its loading fine, and google inspector tool shows the same with no errors. The issue is when I start the page none of the font-family properties change for my h2 or h3 elements

```css
 h2 {
           margin:8px 0;
           padding:8px 0;
           font-size:25px;
           font-weight:bold;
           color:#161616;
           font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
     }
    h3 {
           margin:8px 0;
           font-size: 24px;
           font-weight:bold;
           color: #161616;
           padding-left:8px 0;
           font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
     }
```

```html
    <head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">  
    <title>LLC</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coin-slider.css" />
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-titillium-900.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2> Some Heading </h2>
    <h3> Some More Heading </h2>
    </body>
```

Comment: I put your code into Snipplet and it works fine. What's the problem?

Comment: I think the culprit is cufon. Cufon is a font replacement engine that (depending on the version) changes the font family or the output itself (into VML, SVG or even PNG). So disable this and see if it changes anything

Comment: whenever the webpage loads, it stays in Arial font, but it shows from the google inspector under the styles for h2 and h3 that it is Oswald.

Comment: cufon was the culprit!!! Thank you!!